Problema con CORS en Delphi XE4 DataSnap Server con cliente Angular 17
tengo un servidor DataSnap Rest (desarrollado en delphi XE4) y el cliente es angular. el problema es que puedo perfectamente hacer GET y POST, pero al intentar actualizar (PUT) o borrar (DELETE) un registro, me manda un error de CORS.alguien me puede ayudar por favor.
gracias de antemano:
este es el código en TS:
// agrega un producto al catálogo prefijo "update" metodo post .......
 

    addCatalogo(item: CatData): Observable<CatData>{
        const updData = `${this._locUrl}tabCatalogo`;
        return this._http.post<CatData>(updData, item).pipe(
          map((resp: any) => {
            return resp.result;
         }
        )
      }

// agrega un producto al catálogo prefijo "update" metodo post .......
  

addCatalogo(item: CatData): Observable<CatData>{
    const updData = `${this._locUrl}tabCatalogo`;
    return this._http.post<CatData>(updData, item).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => {
        return resp.result;
   });
  }

Las dos funciones trabajan bien,
// actualiza los datos de un producto el prefijo es "accept" el metodo put...
 

    updCatalogo(item: CatData): Observable<CatData>{
    const modData = `${this._locUrl}tabCatalogo`; 
        return this._http.put<CatData>(modData,item).pipe(
          map ((resp:any)=>{
            return resp.result;
          })
        )   
      }

envía este error: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response
Intenté modificar el webModule en el servidor Datasnap server:
    procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
      Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      if Trim(Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers')) <> '' then
      begin
        Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
          Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        Handled := True;
      end;
      if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
        FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
    end;


Parece bien, pero me llama la atención que estás estableciendo dos veces el header Access-Control-Allow-Methods. Qué pasa si lo dejas solo una vez?

gracias por tu respuesta, así quedó. funciona el GET, el PUT y el POST pero no el DELETE..
 procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
          Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
        begin
          Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
          if Trim(Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers')) <> '' then
          begin
            Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
              Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
            Handled := True;
          end;
          if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
            FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
        end;

